# using Application Insights Appender with log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, azure-application-insights, log4net-appender

I'm having some issues using the ApplicationInsightsAppender for log4net. If I am directly using log4net in the application I can see the logs in app insights, but since I'm using a wrapper around log4net I don't seem to get any of the logs.

Here is a simplified version of my log4net wrapper.

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static Initialize(bool useAIApennder = false)
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        var log = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)_logger.Logger;
        log.Level = Level.All;
        if (useAIApennder )
        {
            log.AddAppender(GetAIAppender(instrumentationKey));
        }
    }

    private static IAppender GetAIAppender(string instrumentationKey)
    {
        // create an ai appender here
    }

    public static void Info(string message)
    {
        ...
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then I'll reference this dll in my project and try and log stuff. I see the local logs fine but I'm not seeing them in app insights. I see all my other app insights stuff just fine though

Comment: Trying to understand when it works and when it doesn't. You're saying that the same Logger class works when it is defined in application itself and when it is defined in helper assembly and referenced from there then it doesn't work?

Comment: yeah so if I just directly use log4net and telemetry client in the project it works okay, but if I use my logger that basically just wraps log4net and my telemetry client that just wraps the AI telemetry client it doesn't work. If I provide my own appender that uses my telemetry client I can get it work, but I don't want to have to do that.

Comment: What's the difference (in code) between using it directly and through wrapper? Is it something besides calling exactly the same code? Is it possible to get a repro for a case when it works and when it doesn't (on my side AI adapter works). Also consider opening github issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server